# .NET Core 2.1 Keeps Coming Back After Uninstall

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have a development VM (Windows Server 2016 Standard) with some apps installed such as Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio 18.6. Our weekly security scans are showing that .NET Core 2.1.30 is installed, which is at end of life and should be removed. I manually uninstall the application from the apps and features control panel, but it mysteriously appears again about a month later. When I was looking at the event viewer while trying to track down who could be installing it, I notice that it is installed by the SYSTEM user. Is there any dependent app that could be reinstalling this automatically after I manually remove it?

Comment: Yes Visual Studio might very well install it. Start Visual Studio, goto menu 'Tools', select 'Get tools and features'. There you can uninstall it.